# Can I set a shortcut in Notepad++ to toggle the tab bar?

Tags: notepad++

I have a particular document that I use to track tasks which I keep "always on-top" (using AutoHotkey), so that it's always visible on the particular desktop that it's open on (I'm using Windows 10).

I want to have this take up as little screen real estate as possible, and so I'm wondering if there's a way to toggle the tab bar using a shortcut, because while I would not like this particular document to show the tab bar, when I switch to my second desktop I have another document that I keep open all the time (using Notepad++), and when using it I *do* want to see the tab bar.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Open Settings > Preference > General > Tab Bar > Hide.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks for the suggestion; I was aware of that option, but I wanted to avoid the hassle of having to change it that way. I should have mentioned that in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can use `F12` to toggle `Post-it` mode which should function as you would like. `Post-it` mode is great for having a small window size and maximizing the text/edit area.